# R taking screenshots from password-protected website

Tags: r, password-protection, httr, webpage-screenshot

I am trying to write a set of R codes to take screenshots from a password-protected website.
I have tried using the `webshot` and `httr` packages but could not figure out a solution for this.
Below are the codes that I have tried.

```
library(httr)
library(webshot)

handle <- handle("url of the home page")
path <- "url of login page"
login <- list(username = "my username", password = "my password", redirect_url = "url of the page that I want to screenshot")

response <- POST(handle = handle, path = path, body = login)

webshot("url of the page that I want to screenshot", "screenshot.png")
```

The screenshot shows the login page instead of the page that I want to screenshot. Which means that the website has not been logged in yet before the screenshot is taken. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Generally there is hesitation on SO when questions appear to be asking for assistance with violations of TOS or subverting copyright or accessing proprietary data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with the RSelenium package. This allows you to fill in the username and password and also has a screenshot function that can take a screenshot of a webpage and save that to disk.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).